# using jquery .trigger when passing object

Tags: jquery

I have 2 checkboxes of class `TheCheckboxClass`, each with a label next to them of class `TheLabelClass`. For the moment, I have an event handler for the checkboxes wired like this:

```
$('#SomeContainer').on({
    mouseup: function () { DoSomethingWithCheckBox($(this)); }
}, '.TheCheckboxClass');
```

As you can see, the checkbox handler passes the checkbox to the function that handles the event.

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="SomeDivClass">
   <input class="TheCheckboxClass" type="checkbox" />
   <div class="TheLabelClass">some text</div>
</div>
```

How can I use `.trigger` to handle a click event on the labels AND pass the corresponding checkbox to the `DoSomethingWithCheckBox` function.

Thanks.

Comment: `$(".TheLabelClass").on('click', function () { $(this).prev().trigger('mouseup'); })` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".TheLabelClass").on('click', function () {
    $(this).prev().trigger('mouseup');
});
```

`.trigger` will fire delegated events too.